# synchronous volley request and get Unexpected response code 400 and request not send to server

Tags: java, android, http, https, android-volley

my synchronous volley request to server have code 400 error but I don,t know why . I searched all questions but answers not work for me . I check API with postman and it work well .

```
    public static String getResponce(final String Url, final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {

    String resulte = "";

    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getContext());


    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, future, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    }){


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            for (int i = 0 ; i < nameValuePairs.size() ; i++){
                params.put(nameValuePairs.get(i).getName() , nameValuePairs.get(i).getValue());
            }

            Log.e("params" , params.toString());

            return params;

        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);

    try {

        resulte =  future.get(30 , TimeUnit.SECONDS); // this will block
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // exception handling
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // exception handling
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resulte;

}
```

nameValuePairs is my request parametrs that add to hashmap in getParams() method.

```
E/Volley: [327] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.goldfishschool.com/api/users/authentication
```

this is my code please help me.

Comment: Use the `JsonObjectRequest` to make a call

Comment: What does 400 mean?

Comment: it means bad request but i dont know exactly .